# Why would InvokeRequired=False via a Delegate.BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, begininvoke

For what reasons would `this.InvokeRequired` equal `False` within `InitUIState()`, as this new thread is being created via a delegate?

My problem is that my label is never being set and `this.BeginInvoke()` is never executing, I imagine it's due to the fact `InvokeRequired` = `False`.

```
    private delegate void BackgroundOperationDelegate(ViewMode mode);
    private BackgroundOperationDelegate backgroundOperationDelegate;

    private void FormControlPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init() {
        this.backgroundOperationDelegate = this.InitUIState;
        this.backgroundOperationDelegate.BeginInvoke(mode, null, null);
    }

    private void InitUIState(ViewMode mode)
    {
        // .. other business logic only here relevant
        // to the worker process ..
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.labelProgramStatus.Text = CONSOLE_IDLE_STATUS;
        });
    }
```

I use this pattern time and time again, but for some reason, this time it's not executing :P
(and yes there is only one instance of `InitUIState()` ever being called, that being from the delegate)

Thanks guys.

Images verifying two distinct threads:
[http://imgur.com/mq12Wl&X5R7G](https://imgur.com/mq12Wl&X5R7G)
[http://imgur.com/mq12W&X5R7Gl](https://imgur.com/mq12W&X5R7Gl)

**Follow up question:** Is this an unpreferred way of creating threads? I've just always found it so simple and lightweight.  Perhaps I should be using `thread.Start()` and I will avoid these issues?

Comment: Please show more code. Is this Windows Forms? When is Init() being called?

Comment: Jon, I am honoured of your presence! This is a windows forms app, Init() is within the Form_Load() routine.  Food for thought though, the form that has labels changing upon it is currently invisible (this.Visible=False), the reason for this is a procedure in it has been called upon via another form to update the UI, the form will then be displayed with the most current UI when the user double clicks [this] form in the system tray to display it to the screen.

Comment: @GONeale: It's probably okay for it to be invisible, but has the GDI handle even been created? If not, that could explain why InvokeRequired is false - it may not be ready yet. What happens if you try putting it in the HandleCreated event handler instead?

Comment: Well, Immediate Window tells me this.IsHandleCreated equals True.  It might be execution state lying to me though, I will try wrapping it in that and recompiling.

Comment: @GONeale: Is this an accurate portrayal of what your code is doing? It seems to me you are sending some work off to the threadpool only to pull it straight back to the GUI (this is what `this.BeginInvoke` does). Why not just run the code from the GUI thread to begin with?

Comment: No it's not.  There is more code, but it's irrelevant business logic to this question. I didn't want to bloat this thread. Let's just say there is worker thread logic that occurs first.

Comment: @GONeale: OK, I should have figured as much. Just checking.

Comment: Are you sure `InvokeRequired == false` from the threadpool thread? If you're checking this from the VS debugger it might be inaccurate. Did you try logging it? Also: your *real* question is why your `this.BeginInvoke` call doesn't execute, right? It seems to me that the value of `InvokeRequired` shouldn't really have an impact on this. It must be something else.

Comment: Ok thanks Dan.  I understand what you mean and I felt it might be inaccurate, but can't be certain.  Yes my real question is why this label does not get set.  I have attached two images to my post which verifies the two distinct thread processes.

Comment: HOLD THE PHONE everybody. Dan was correct, after testing Jon's code of the Handle once more, and not through quick watch.. but via:
var hc = this.IsHandleCreated;
var ir = this.InvokeRequired;
The debugger (quick watch) was lying to me. Both variables returned FALSE! This confirms why the BI probably isn't running and why InvokeRequired = False.

Comment: More interesting insight, it appeared through some advice wrapping my this.BeginInvoke() in a try,catch revealed an "InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." which we're all familiar with and this is why it never ran, and it's all because obviously InvokeRequired equaled false due to the null window handle. I didn't see this try catch because somehow it got gobbled up and this was the last operation in my method, I thought it was just resuming run mode! Fun and games.

Comment: I will award the points to bleevo as he displays obviously my way to get around the window handle, the standard if test.  However for those interested, I used a neater InvokeRequired extension method from this post to handle it generically, and I can confirm everything is working now like a dreaaaaaam.  http://psychocoder.net/index.php/2010/07/03/extension-methods-invokerequired/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd BeginInvoke will throw an Exception.

Try

```
private void InitUIState(ViewMode mode)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            InitUIState(mode);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.labelProgramStatus.Text = CONSOLE_IDLE_STATUS;
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in comments, due to my win handle not being created this is the reason my thread in this instance still allowed me to update the UI thread directly. A very rare occurrence I would think!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing BeginInvoke of Form and Delegate, as both of them have same method name.

Form's method, BeginInvoke calls the method you are requested in the same UI thread, but on a later stage, after processing its own pending UI operations. This is the reason, InvokeRequired will always be false within the Form's BeginInvoke's method.

Delegate's method, BeginInvoke calls the method on a new thread asynchronously in thread pool. And InvokeRequired in delegate's BeginInvoke will always be true.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help me.  I am not mixing them, this.BeginInvoke() will execute it's contents on the main UI thread.  delegate.BeginInvoke() will execute it's contents on a new worker item in ThreadPool.  This doesn't explain to me why InvokeRequired=false.

Comment: Whenever anything executes on UI thread, InvokeRequired will be false, sorry cant explain better then this.

Comment: No that's fine, you are right. I am not setting the label on the UI thread. delegate.BeginInvoke() does this on a worker thread.  So InvokeRequired will equal True.

Answer (score -1):

`Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` on delegates are not the same as `ISynchronizeInvoke`.

Also you need to call `EndInvoke` when dealing with a delegate.

Comment: @GONeale: You do, if you dont want to leak the WaitHandle. But I guess that is up to you.